# Debug Local Spring Heroku App on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, debugging, heroku

I was wondering if anyone knows how to set up Eclipse to debug a heroku app locally? On Heroku it shows how to locally deploy the app using this command "java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war" on cmd but is there a way to run the app on Eclipse?

Thank you

Comment: I normally just develop and debug using local Tomcat installation e.g. TC Server if you are using the Spring Tools Suite Eclipse bundle. You can also run it using the embedded Webapp-Runner following the instructions here https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner. Any Heroku environemnt variables your app depends on can be passed as server startup args.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! If you could just put your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct. (:

Comment: I'll second @AlanHay 's comment re: TC Server. Additionally, you should try `foreman`, which is installed with the Heroku toolbelt. This allows you to more closely emulate the server environment (e.g., multiple dynos). To enable debugging, exec `export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n"`. Then you can debug as a remote server w/in eclipse. Caveat - that fails when running 2 dynos because of port conflicts. Quick fix: set unique `JAVA_OPTS` in separate terminals and start a single `foreman` instance in each.